# Node.js memory leak in streams

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks

I detected a strange increase of the memory usage in an express.js application and after a lot of investigation I discovered that the problem was caused while writing to a file using writable streams.

To isolate the problem I created this simple app:

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');

var app = express();


app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

var writable = fs.createWriteStream('/tmp/stream', {flags: 'a'});

var i = 1;
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    i = i + 1;
    writable.write(i + '\n');
    res.end();
});

app.get('/flush', function (req, res) {
    writable.end();
    res.end();
});

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function () {
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

After launching several requests with a benchmark tool and analyzing the memory used with 'top', I realized that it grows and is never released.

The call to the flush route after finishing the requests doesn't free the memory either.

Is this a memory leak or I'm doing something wrong?

I've made the tests with node 0.8.6, 0.10.37 and 0.12.7 with the same results.

Comment: How much memory is being used, and how many times are you calling the `/` route? It could be that the stream's buffer is growing normally, and not a memory leak. When you call `/flush` it could be that the GC hasn't gotten around to running yet.

Comment: The memory used depends on the number and frequency of the requests, the important thing is that is constantly growing. The route is called a lot, probably more often than what the stream can handle, which would explain the memory growth. The problem is that when you stop sending the requests and everything has been written in the file, the memory size should go back to its inicial state, which doesn't seem to happen.

Comment: The garbage collector can idle along for quite a while before freeing up memory. If you run `node --expose-gc` and then call `global.gc()` after the flush operation, is the memory still around?

Comment: It seems to free some memory but with 'top' is difficult to say if recovers completely or not. I'm trying to get a wider view of the memory usage in a larger period of time.